502 bad gateway Error while using Azure as Backend
I am trying to post data to my database which is hosted in Azure in React using Axios. Please help me solve this problem. I have crossed check all the naming convention which links to the database, all that is correct still can't figure out what is the actual issue here. Any leads will be helpful.
Error Message: "Request failed with status code 502"
const handleSubmit = (event) => {  
      event.preventDefault();  
      const updatedFormData = {  
        courseName: courseName,  
        endProgramDates: endDate,  
        endTime: endTime,  
        format: customFormat || selectedFormat,  
        registrationLink: registration,  
        source: source,  
        startProgramDates: startDate,  
        startTime: startime,
        targetAudience: selectedTA, 
      };  
      setFormData(updatedFormData);  
      const url = 'www.api.com';  
      console.log(formData)
      formData.map(response=>{
        console.log("456789e3iuhr37gryuj")
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      axios.post(url, formData)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
      }); 
};

Let me provide you format in which data in sending using that api
{
  "courseName": "React - Testing",
  "endProgramDates": "02-08-2024",
  "endTime": " 8:00 PM IST",
  "format": "VILT",
  "registrationLink": "www.google.com",
  "source": "live",
  "startProgramDates": "01-08-2024",
  "startTime": " 6:00 PM IST",
  "targetAudience": "Live"
}


502 is a bad gateway, which normally means your server is not communicating with the public correctly. I think this is a config issue, can you post your Azure config?

Azure service is not up yet. That means service is unavailable

@ViaTech the issue got solved, it unique Id issue. Thanks for the help

@ViaTech I got another doubt that, if I want to add the data in bulk, say using an excel sheet. Then how can we achieve that in azure? I tried to doing with same api/logicApp but it not accepting. What changes or kind of logic app should I create to make it happen?

@AbhishekSrinivasanUS create a Logic App that triggers when a new file is added to a specific location (e.g., a storage account), reads the data from the Excel file, and sends it to your API for insertion. Configure the Logic App to trigger when a new file is added to your storage account. Then, add actions to read the data from the Excel file and send it to your API.

Thanks @Sampath  but I kind of tried this. It wasn't working as expected. Can you please provide detailed steps I might have messed up something.

@Abhishek Srinivasan US please also add the things you tried and where it failed as well

I tried doing with the trigger you mentioned but was confused what parameters should be added since I am new to making logic apps in azure. So carried on with the POST API which posts one data at a time. But was getting 502 gateway error. Can you suggest changes in code such that it accepts the data regardless of it is single or bulk?
